# Instantiate class and set properties from the editor view Unity C#

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, editor, instance

I have the following class :

```
[Serializable]
public class BaseDamage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int MaximumDamage;
    public int MinimumDamage;
    public short SpellScaling;
}
```

and a class which contains that class :

```
public class SpellDamage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BaseDamage SpellBaseDamage;
}
```

When I attach `SpellDamage` script to a gameObject I want to be able to set the value of `BaseDamage` from the editor view, but it just allows me to attach a script to it.

how can i do that ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible, but if so, it most likely requires some custom editor scripts. An option would also be to have `SpellDamage` inherit from `BaseDamage` (that class doesn't need `Serializable` by the way).

Comment: even if it inherits i still have the `SpellDamage` class in another class so it's still impossible ot instantiate it from the editor

Comment: In that case you should remember that unity is a component based system. Make the `Damage` class be a component  (just attach that to respective gameobject (e.g. the player) and set the values) and have other scripts have a reference to that component.

Comment: Also, you can always pass values to a class in e.g. `Start`.

Comment: **never, ever** use "Serializable".  As a curiosity where did you even see that?  Delete it.

Comment: "public BaseDamage SpellBaseDamage" variable names MUST start with lower case.

Comment: You are not right @JoeBlow. The public one's should be exactly like that.

Comment: you are thinking of properties.  this is unity, a public inspector variable is just a variable, not a property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. You can attach the BaseDamage script to the same gameobject which SpellDamage script is attached to.

You've added the `Serializable` attribute. What you need to do is write a **Custom Property Drawer** for `BaseDamage` class inside **Editor** folder.

Something like this:

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(BaseDamage))]
public class BaseDamageDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{


static string[] propNames = new[]
{
    "MaximumDamage",
    "MinimumDamage",
    "SpellScaling",
};



public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
{
    // Using BeginProperty / EndProperty on the parent property means that
    // prefab override logic works on the entire property.
    EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

    // Draw label
    position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), label);

    // Don't make child fields be indented
    var indent = EditorGUI.indentLevel;
    EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;

    SerializedProperty[] props = new SerializedProperty[propNames.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
    {
        props[i] = property.FindPropertyRelative(propNames[i]);
    }


    // Calculate rects
    float x = position.x;
    float y = position.y;
    float w = position.width / props.Length;
    float h = position.height;
    for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
    {
        var rect = new Rect(x, y, w, h);
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect, props[i], GUIContent.none);
        x += position.width / props.Length;
    }

    // Set indent back to what it was
    EditorGUI.indentLevel = indent;

    EditorGUI.EndProperty();
}
```